why some residual pixels contain weird images in VVC extracted information?
I have implemented a code to extract information from VVC Test Machine (VTM).
It works well most of the time, but for some CTUs it shows weird images such as these:


I wanted to see some pictures that the the parts with motion look different, such as these:


I couldn't find the reason for these images, while I use the very similar code for data extraction in VTM:
CPelBuf ResiPelYinME = m_bestModeUpdated ? bestCS->getResiBuf().bufs[0] : tempCS->getResiBuf().bufs[0];
  

can anybody help me with this problem?

Familiar with earlier codecs but not H.266. Can you show what you expect these to look like? My original guess is that you're looking at residuals and the "blank" ones could just be skipped (i.e. they're identical to their reference block). But I'm not sure if that's what you mean when you say that they look "odd".

@Pam I needed to see the pixels with high motion. my ultimate goal is to use this residual image for fast CU partitioning method. I added some images to the question.

Are you sure the weird pictures are predicted? Sometimes an encoder will make the decision to use spatial prediction (intra) rather than temporal (inter) prediction if it can’t find a match that beats it or if there’s a need to build an entry point into the stream. H.263 and older used to require a whole key frame every 30 frames or less. Newer codecs like to build key frames up over time to avoid bitrate peaks or quality drops.

@Pam the images that I've attached are the residuals of Motion Estimation (ME) mode of VVC. So I'm sure that it's not intra-predicted.
